# Why do some madhabs insist on reciting Surah Yasin [thrice] on 15th of Shaban?

Tags: hadith, fiqh, ritual, surat-yasin

I have seen many folks [especially from hanafi madhab] state that it is a sunnah to recite Surah Yasin after Maghrib on 15th of Shaban after one has returned back home from the graveyards praying for their dead.

Where can I find a daleel on the subject?

Comment: It's the b'day of Mahdi (p.b.u.h.) AFAIK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This state is false, there is no evidence that it is sunnah, the prophet never did it neither did the companions.